# Exception when calling web service asynchronously

Tags: c#, web-services, asynchronous, apache-axis

I'm using ASMX to call some Axis2 web service methods. When calling the Axis2 methods synchronously, they work flawlessly. The problem is when I call my methods asynchronously: I have subscribed to the "Completed" event for one of my web services so it would trigger my EventHandler when it's done. After the web service finishes, the following exception is thrown:

```
System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Exception occurred while trying to invoke service method validateSurname at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.ReadResponse(SoapClientMessage message, WebResponse response, Stream responseStream, Boolean asyncCall) at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.InvokeAsyncCallback(IAsyncResult result)
```

I have other JAXRPC web services that I'm calling asynchronously, and they are working flawlessly.

Does anyone have an idea about the problem?

Note: We're still using .NET 2.0

Comment: There is no InnerException? that message is not very clear...

Comment: The problem is that my InnerException is null! The only thing it contains is this System.Exception._COMPlusExceptionCode( Value -532459699) which doesn't mean anything I guess.

Comment: hehe, It means a lot, let me take a look

Comment: Hi. There is no other code given with the error? that code is the standar code for "COM exception", there should be another negative number with the actual error code

Comment: Thanks for putting the time in man. There's something called _HResult that has a value of -2146233087. I don't know if this is relevant.

Comment: Yes, that's the real exception code, give me 5 minutos ;)

Comment: Well, you are out of luck, it means "Unknown error", so it does not help, sorry

Comment: Hey, an idea, instead of using a reference to the web service you can use wsdl to generate a .cs file with all the code for the soap client, in this way you will see exactly where it crashes

Comment: I will create a separate project to do that and let you know what I find out. Thanks a ton @Gusman

Comment: Hope it sheds some light.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was very simple: I was sending a null array to the web service.